# Why is server.js never built in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am using `Vue.js 3` for my front end, and Node/Express on the back-end. I am trying to enable server side rendering which is proving difficult.

I understand the client-side is built into a file called `app.js`. However I never see `server.js` being built and exported to the `dist` folder? Here are some examples:

1. [vue-hackernews](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) where there is an `entry-client.js` and `entry-server.js` file being provided to Webpack, but `server.js` is not anywhere to be seen.
2. Another [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899690/vue-3-server-side-rendering-with-vuex-and-router) also only provides `main.server.js` as the server entry file and does not build `server.js`.

It is my understanding that `server.js` is the back-end and has to run for Node.js/Express to work. In the above two examples what exactly is being built from the server entry files because it doesn't seem to be `server.js` where the Express routes live. Surely `server.js` must be built to the dist folder so that it can be accessed and run by a web server like Windows IIS for example (which I am using)?

Comment: webpack config, for "production" can include a 2nd config block that pertains just to server.js ( its own output in ./dist) . .  module.exports = [ { conf-1 }, {#2} ]  in order to use dev-server & HMR, you would have separate config for "development"

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, usually there is no need to bundle the server code.

But there are some benefits from doing so:

1. One project wide configuration, must of the client & server config can be shared - no need to maintain multiple build tools
2. Server code HMR (Hot Module Replacement)- you can swap your server code during dev without the need to restart the server
3. Code sharing between client & server
4. Code transpilation - server code can be written in modern syntax (ESM etc...) and it will be transpiled to the target node version.

Comment: So how does the web server run `server.js` if it is not in the dist folder? What if the `server.js` uses ES6+ syntax?

Comment: Regarding  es6 syntax, it depends on the config, but usually you can transpile the server code to a specific node version

Comment: Regarding server.js, I'm not sure I understood the question

Comment: Regarding server.js, `server.js` doesn't need to be in a dist folder, it is not a magic folder, the file can be anywhere, all you need in order to run it, is to `node ./what-ever/folder/server.js`

Comment: I meant as part of the build & deploy process, how is `server.js` taken care of? Are people literally copying/pasting the file to the production server?!

Comment: It is a valid option, other option is to point webpack to output to dist

Comment: my `server.js` has requires in it from other folders in the `src`. An example is `server.use('/api/v1', cors(), require('./router/api/v1'));` where `router` is in `./src/router`. If I run `server.js` within `dist` then I get errors like `Error: Cannot find module './router/api/v1'` How can this be solved because `router` won't exist in the `dist` folder.

Comment: is your server is boundled?  is `server.js` is the entry point of the bundle?

Comment: Hi felixmosh. I have added a new question which describes my problem here - could you possibly help please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230349/how-do-i-build-server-js-with-webpack-5