# Vue 3: How to create SSR + SPA functionality for a CMS engine?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, single-page-application, hydration, vue-ssr

We have a CMS where we are trying to provide the support of VueJS framework to our client websites. The views and their logic will be coded from the CMS Panel itself. The problem comes when trying to render the website having the support for both SPA and SSR due to SEO.

When client requests for a page, the SSR should work during that time but once the page is rendered, the SPA should take the control and let the user navigate(vue-router) wihtout page reload as it works in Vue SPA.

I checked on with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899690/vue-3-server-side-rendering-with-vuex-and-router) and it won't help due to my unique requirement. There are no static bundles available for my case.

Any help will be appreciated!

I have tried many examples to achive this however they aren't exactly helping for my case.

https://github.com/0x00000001A/vuejs-spa-ssr-vuex

https://github.com/shenron/vue3-example-ssr

Answer (score 0):

You may need [nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/). It can help you spa+ssr on vue

Comment: I did explore NuxtJs. That will not work since the websites are created using cms and have highly dynamic content. NuxtJs applications are bundled as static sites whereas in my case the applications/components will be coded from the browser directly and conditionally rendered from a single server(Website render engine)!